# Калькулятор на JS (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, нужно сделать калькулятор по формуле
value1*(value2+value3)

я сделал так,
но при вводе например 2*(2+2) должно  быть = 8 , а возвращает 44
подскажите в чем проблема?

```js
 jQuery('#value1').bind('input', function() {
   jQuery("#summ").html(+($(this).val()) *(($("#value2").val()) + +($("#value3").val())));

});
jQuery('#value2').bind('input', function() {
 jQuery("#summ").html(+($("#value1").val()) *(($(this).val()) + +($("#value3").val())));
});
jQuery('#value3').bind('input', function() {
  jQuery("#summ").html(+($("#value1").val()) *(($("#value2").val()) + +($(this).val())));
});
```

```css
.row-flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.row-flex label{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="row-flex">
<div><label>Value1</label> <input id="value1" type="text" />*(</div>
<div><label>Value2</label> <input id="value2" type="text" />+</div>
<div><label>Value3</label> <input id="value3" type="text" />)</div>
</form>
=
<div class="result"><span id="summ"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Читать код труднее, чем писать. Давайте писать так, чтобы было легко читать.

```js
$('#value1, #value2, #value3').bind('input', calcAndShow);

function calcAndShow() {
  var v1 = parseFloat($("#value1").val());
  var v2 = parseFloat($("#value2").val());
  var v3 = parseFloat($("#value3").val());

  $("#summ").html(v1 * (v2 + v3));
}
```

```css
.row-flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.row-flex label{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="row-flex">
<div><label>Value1</label> <input id="value1" type="text" />*(</div>
<div><label>Value2</label> <input id="value2" type="text" />+</div>
<div><label>Value3</label> <input id="value3" type="text" />)</div>
</form>
=
<div class="result"><span id="summ"></span></div>
```

Comment: `parseFloat` :(

Answer (score 3):

1. Во всех трёх строчках у второго инпута потерялся унарный плюс.
2. Код надо писать так, чтобы эта строчка была в одном месте, а не в трёх.
3. Не надо присваивать `html`, если там не планируется разметки.
4. У `label`ов надо бы использовать `for` или класть инпут внутрь.

```js
$('form').on('input', 'input', function() {
  $("#summ").text(+$("#value1").val() * (+$("#value2").val() + +$("#value3").val()));
});
```

```css
.row-flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}

.row-flex label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="row-flex">
  <div><label for="value1">Value1</label> <input id="value1" type="text" />*(</div>
  <div><label for="value2">Value2</label> <input id="value2" type="text" />+</div>
  <div><label for="value3">Value3</label> <input id="value3" type="text" />)</div>
</form>
=
<div class="result"><span id="summ"></span></div>
```

Comment: Плохая экономия, аж две строчки лишних! 
`$('form').on('input', 'input', e => $("#summ").text(+$("#value1").val() * (+$("#value2").val() + +$("#value3").val())));`

Comment: @Darth, а я ничего не экономил)